# Node.js, dgram.setBroadcast(flag) fails due to "EBADF"

Tags: node.js

I'm using Node.js 0.6.9, and am trying to send a datagram broadcast package. Code:

```
var sys = require('util');
var net = require('net');

var dgram = require('dgram');
var message = new Buffer('message');
var client = dgram.createSocket("udp4");
client.setBroadcast(true);
client.send(message, 0, message.length, 8282, "192.168.1.255", function(err, bytes) {
  client.close();
});
```

Running the code:

```
$ node test.js
node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: setBroadcast EBADF
    at errnoException (dgram.js:352:11)
    at Socket.setBroadcast (dgram.js:227:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/letharion/tmp/collision/hello.js:25:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:444:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:462:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:351:32)
    at Function._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Array.0 (module.js:482:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:41)
```

Some googling [reveals](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/glibc-manual-0.02/library_15.html) that "EBADF" means "The socket argument is not a valid file descriptor". But I don't understand enough about the problem for that to be helpful.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

First of all, you seem to have trouble understanding the format of the stacktrace, so let's clarify it before we go to the actual error that is thrown here.

### Format of a node.js Stacktrace

```
node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
```

This part is just the location where the internal NodeJS logic choked up and put out the error below:

The actual error stacktrace follows, it shows the **deepest** location in the callstack first, so going **down** in the stack trace, brings you **up** in the call hierachy, eventually leading you to the point in your code where everything began.

```
Error: setBroadcast EBADF
    at errnoException (dgram.js:352:11)
    at Socket.setBroadcast (dgram.js:227:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/letharion/tmp/collision/hello.js:25:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:444:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:462:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:351:32)
    at Function._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Array.0 (module.js:482:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:41)
```

First it fails in [`dgram.js on line 352`](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.6/lib/dgram.js#L354), `dgram.js` is a internal node.js module abstracting the "low level" code. Line `352` is in a function containing generic logic for throwing errors.

It was called at [`dgram.js in line 227`](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.6/lib/dgram.js#L227), after a failed if check which wraps the call to the wrapped native UDP sockets `setBroadcast` method.

Going up one more layer, we end up at your `hello.js` file on line `25` with the `client.setBroadcast(true);` call.

The rest is more node.js code resulting from the initial load of the `hello.js` file.

### The actual Error

The error thrown by the native code which node.js wraps here is `EBADF` [looking this up in conjunction with `UDP`](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/glibc-manual-0.02/library_15.html) gives us:

```
EBADF
    The socket argument is not a valid file descriptor.
```

By going further down into the node.js rabbit hole, we end up in the [udp wrapper](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.6/src/udp_wrap.cc), which wraps the [uv wrapper](https://github.com/joyent/libuv/blob/master/include/uv.h) for the actual C implementation, in the uv wrapper we find:

```
/*
* Set broadcast on or off
*
* Arguments:
* handle UDP handle. Should have been initialized with
* `uv_udp_init`.
* on 1 for on, 0 for off
*
* Returns:
* 0 on success, -1 on error.
*/
```

Leading us to the conclusion that your socket has not been initialized yet.

**In the end, binding the socket via `client.bind(8000)`** fixed the missing initialization and made the program run.

Comment: That was an absolutely great answer! Thank you very much. I would have created a bounty just to award it, but it seems I cannot. I guess it's because the question is to new.

Comment: One of the best answers I've seen on SO.

Comment: While extensive on the node.js stacktrace part, the answer should be updated to indicate that the client.setBroadcast(true); and client.send(...) functions should only be called from within the bind callback (i.e. we should not assume bind is synchronous)

Answer (score 28):

The method `setBroadcast` should be called on `'listening'` event or passed as callback in `bind` method:

```
var socket = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

socket.on('listening', function(){
    socket.setBroadcast(true);
});

socket.bind(8000);
```

OR:

```
var socket = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

socket.bind(8000, undefined, function() {
    socket.setBroadcast(true);
});
```

Comment: this should be the correct answer, cause the bind is async

Comment: You can probably do one better and put it on the end of the bind: `sockt.bind(port,undefined,()=>{socket.setBroadcast(true);})`

Answer (score 4):

It seems like the file descriptor is created only on bind or on send, and it's required before setBroadcast. You can call `client.bind()` with no parameter to bind to a random port before setting broadcast. Don't worry about using a random port, since it's done "lazily" when using `client.send` anyway.

```
var sys = require('util');
var net = require('net');

var dgram = require('dgram');
var message = new Buffer('message');
var client = dgram.createSocket("udp4");
client.bind();
client.setBroadcast(true);
client.send(message, 0, message.length, 8282, "192.168.1.255", function(err, bytes) {
    client.close();
});
```

Comment: that's not 100% correctly and should fail with the same error. You have to set the broadcast flag in the callback of the bind method!

Comment: @soupdiver `client.bind` was synchronous when this answer was posted.